# Qt: How to make sure the protocol between server-client is always TLS and never fall to SSL?

Tags: qt, sockets, ssl, server, tls1.2

I am using Qt5 on Windows 7.
I currently have a server app that uses a QSslSocket to communicate with clients.
It works ok so far, but the customer wants me to use **only TLS** protocol, and make sure we never fall down to SSL protocol (which he considers to be not secure enough).
In my code there's absolutely nothing set explicitly, I only used the default(s) offered by the QSslSocket class.
I saw in Qt doc that by default QSslSocket uses TLSv1_0, yet I am not quite sure, because...
On the other hand, the Qt doc says, see QSsl::SecureProtocols: "The default option, using protocols known to be secure; currently behaves similar to TlsV1Ssl3 except denying SSLv3 connections that does not upgrade to TLS."
So, I am a little bit puzzled about this...
Finally, the question is: Would the default (what I have right now) of QSslSocket class guarantee that the connection is TLS encrypted? If not, what should I do in order to be sure the connection always uses TLS protocol?

Comment: The sentence *"I saw in Qt doc that by default QSslSocket uses TLSv1_0"* conflicts with *"On the other hand, the Qt doc says, see QSsl::SecureProtocols: "The default option""*. Where did you read the first one?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html  , at `Detailed Description`, check row #4. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the note, [I'll fix the documentation](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/161478) now. Anyhow: SecureProtocols (the default) does what you want. If it gets TLS, fine; if it gets SSLv3 it asks for upgrade to TLS, if the peer doesn't upgrade the handshake fails.

Comment: @peppe: Thanks Giuseppe! Is it you who developed/maintains the related library `QSslSocket` for Qt ? Regards, SG.

Comment: I'm not the maintainer, I'm just a guy working for a company which regularly contributes code to Qt. :-)

Comment: Peppe, please allow me one more question: The type of certificate (or keys) have any influence somehow on the communication protocol? I mean: do I need special generated certificates/keys in order to have a TLS protocol between client and server? Must the certificates be generated especially for TLS? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the cerificates are the same.